# cross domain ajax request fails in android device

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

i have a very basic jqm/phonegap app

here is my html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body >
<div data-role="page" id="home"  >
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>p</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" style="text-align:right" id="c1">


  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is my js code which is placed in the body of html code

```
 <script>

    function get_news_list(id , link_ , refresh_ ){

        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        $.ajax({
        url :  link_ ,  
        success:function(data){
            $('#c1').html(data);

                        } ,
        error : function(data) {

            alert(data.toSource);

            }
        });
    }

  get_news_list('latest' , 'http://pnup.ir/?feed=json' , refresh_);

    </script>
```

when i run it as a webpage i get

this alert 
   if firefox

```
function toSource() {
    [native code]
}
```

in chrome

```
  undefined
```

which i assume is ok cuz it's a cross domain ajax request and it fails in a web browser (altho in firebug it's status is ok 200 it just doesn't return anything as response ) 
but when i test it on my android device i get the same `undefined` . i thought cross domain ajax request isn't problem once i rune it as app in android device ?

am i missing something ? should i use jsonp ? its a wordpress website and with json feed plugin its feeds are available in json but getting jsonp feed would be a nightmare ... at least i dont know how !

Answer (score 1):

i implemented jsonp recently in one of my phonegap + jquerymobile project, i had the same issue but i used asp.net for my services

calling the service like below worked for me all you have to do is add ?fnCallBack=? at the end of the url

```
$.ajax({        
        url : link_+'?fnCallBack=?',
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        jsonp : 'json',
        cache : false,
        success : function(result) {
            if (result != 'Error') {
                var valX = JSON.stringify(result);
                valX = JSON.parse(valX);
            } else {
                navigator.notification.alert("An error occured, Please try later");
            }
        }
    });
```

and on the server side when you send json response just add fnCallBack like this

```
        string jsoncallback = context.Request["fnCallBack"];
        context.Response.Write(string.Format("{0}({1})", jsoncallback,jsonData));
```

this way i solved my cross domain issue so hoping you ll get a clue from this